# "Go To Definition" from a .xaml.cs file takes me to .g.i.cs files instead of to .xaml file in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, go-to-definition

I am used to Visual Studio Go To Definition (or ReSharper's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + left click) in code behind on an element name defined in XAML to take me directly to XAML of that element. For some reason it's taking me to `.g.i.cs` file instead. Where as it's not a huge problem it is annoying as hell. This is also not specific to my project - I can create a new WPF project, add a single button to XAML and get the same result trying to go to the button's declaration in XAML from code behind file.

I tried to do the same thing in VS 2015 Professional on another computer and get the same problem.

But when I do this in Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 on my Surface, it works correctly and goes to XAML (all testing done with new WPF project) - I can't find any option anywhere that would control this.

Any ideas for this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think, the answer is basically, that Visual Studio does not support this, which is exactly why ReSharper includes such a functionality.

Comment: I will verify this information, but I was under the impression VS supports this.

Comment: Verified - Visual Studio definitely supports this feature (without Resharper). Still looking for help :)

Comment: Ok, doing further research this seems to be caused by Resharper. After installing resharper the normal navigation broke.

Comment: Maybe ReSharper unsets the default keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Well, it seems as ReSharper actually changed the behavior - very naughty. I am happy to say that ReSharper 9.2 fixed this problem (I was using 9.1.3 initially). Thanks for helping me go through this

Comment: I dont have Resharper installed (never had it installed in this machine) and I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately my issue was very specific to resharper. Do you have any other extensions installed? if you do, disable them, try the system, and then enable them one by one to see if any one of them is causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems as ReSharper actually changed the behavior - very naughty. I am happy to say that ReSharper 9.2 fixed this problem (I was using 9.1.3 initially).